# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n\tan\left(\frac {\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty}n\tan\left( \dfrac { \pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)$ converge or diverge? My idea was to use the limit comparison test and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {n}{2^{n}}$, but then I don't know what to do with the tangent which in the limit is 0.

Comment: Please consider using \tan to get $\tan$ instead of $tan$. For example, your $ntan$ would appear as $n\tan$. Also, consider using \left( and \right) to get larger brackets, e.g. $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ instead of $(\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: @Cameron: Is there a particular reason for the rollback?

Comment: I assume your index should be $n$, not $i$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Only just because of dfrac. You edited it immediately after I finished editing but I wanted to keep the fraction relatively readable in the inline equation.

Comment: @Dror Check out the edits to the question

Comment: @Cameron: I edited *while* you edited, not after. I agree that the `\dfrac` is reasonable here (although I try to avoid using it in titles).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Quite right. Sorry if I upset you by rolling back!

Comment: @Cameron: It's fine. I was just curious about that, nothing more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)} = 1
$$

Comment: Where did the n in front of the tangent function go?

Comment: This isn't a direct manipulation of the sum; this is just a fact that you can use.  It will help if you want to use the ratio test on the sum itself.

Answer (score 3):

We have that, as $(\tan x)'=\sec^2 x$, then, for every $x\in [0,\pi/4]$, there exists a $\vartheta\in (0,1)$, such that
$$
\tan x=\tan x -\tan 0=x\sec^2 \vartheta x, 
$$
and hence
$$
\lvert\tan x\rvert \le 2\lvert x\rvert,  
$$
since for $x\in [0,\pi/4]$
$$
1\le \sec x\le \sqrt{2}.
$$
Clearly, $\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\in [0,\pi/4]$, and  thus
$$
0\le \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)\le \frac{\pi}{2^n},
$$
and as the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n2^{-n}$ converges (i.e., ratio test), so does the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right),
$$ 
and it does absolutely.

Comment: I think you mean that $(\tan x)' = \sec^2 x$.. :)

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I corrected it. Thanx.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis. Any idea about the result of the summation ? The value $3.40841$ does not look very appealing to RIES.